# Pause / debug / print stack trace on failure for many Protractor test cases?

Tags: javascript, protractor

With dozens of automated tests and an app with lots of variability, I'm looking for the easiest way to quickly trace down errors and keep test cases well maintained. I want to be able to run many tests in parallel and pause any test case at its fail point so I can easily modify locators/functionality when needed.

I wrap my clicks in a global function so I can make some additional checks...

```
onPrepare: function() {
    global.clickElement = function (elem) {
        isElemDisplayed(elem);
        elem.click();
        checkForErrorScreen();
    });
}
```

If an element is not displayed before I click it *or any* failure occurs, I want to immediately:

1. **Pause the browser**
2. **Take Screenshot** (just in case/logging purposes)
3. **Print error / stack trace**

I've found I can pause the browser "when spec fails" thanks to @holdfenytolvaj

```
onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        specDone: function (spec) {
            if (spec.status === 'failed') {
                console.dir(spec.failedExpectations.length);
                console.log(spec.failedExpectations[0].message);
                console.log(spec.failedExpectations[0].stack);
                browser.pause()
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What types of failures does this actually pause on? I want to pause on *any* failure.

Also, I can immediately spit out the failure/trace *sometimes* via

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    realtimeFailure: true
},
```

Again, what types of failures will this actually display the failure/stack?

Checking if elements are displayed using my global click wrapper, I can never get a full trace back to what function / locator it failed on. So I look at the `ElementFinder` obj in the debugger and can see *just* the child locator in case I want to log it

```
var elem = $('div.parent').$('div[ng-show="child"]');

function isElemDisplayed(elem) {
    var locator = elem.parentElementArrayFinder.locator_.value; // 'div[ng-show="child"]'
    //check isDisplayed()...
}
```

Is there a way to display the entire locator for chained elements or a totally different approach to handling this issue so I can immediately display what locator is failing?

These are just some methods I've picked up thru Google and tried. I'm really looking for tips/conventions/snippets you guys have used to make your debugging faster.